# AWS S3 Versioning ON: can I delete all objects from my bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am trying clarify whether it is possible to permanently delete all objects from my bucket if the Versioning is set to ON. From AWS:

"To permanently delete versioned objects, you must use DELETE Object versionId. The following figure shows that deleting a specified object version permanently removes that object."

Does it mean that I can programmatically remove objects for good via my lambda? Can I also use the lifecycle rule to remove all objects after a certain period of time (e.g. after 1 day they have been received into my bucket)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can delete specific versions of an object by providing the version ID in the request.

Yes, you can also use Lifecycle Rules to delete objects and prior versions.

Give it a try. If you have a specific problem, feel free to ask a question with more details.